# Install specific python library version based on another library version

Tags: python, setup.py

In setup.py I have

```
    install_requires=[
           "python-consul",
           "library_a",
           "library_b"
    ]
```

library_b is also imported by library_a but it is pinned in library_a.

Is it possible to pin library_b to what it is pinned in library_a. I know I can just pin the same version but then everytime library_b pin is updated in library_a I need to repin in my service.

Comment: If B is pinned in A, then just pin A. Done. Or am I missing something? You probably should either curate this list yourself by hand (to make sure that all versions are vetted by you), or use tools to do this automatically, there are plenty of them floating around, _pip-tools_ comes to mind. Also `install_requires` is probably not the best location to do such thing, but it all depends on your needs.

Comment: I had just pinned library_a but it picked up the latest version of library_b when installing.

Comment: So B is not pinned in A, do we agree on that? The question should reflect that.

Comment: Sorry library_b is pinned in library_a. Even if I don't pin library_b in my setup.py it installs the latest version of library_b not the version required by library_a.

Comment: I am confused, I must be misunderstanding something. Could you clarify what you mean by "_library_b is pinned in library_a_"? From my point of view if B is pinned in A, it means that when installing A, the exact needed version of B is automatically selected for install as well. Is that a phrasing we can agree on? It would make it easier to help you if you could be more explicit, maybe edit your question to add clarifications, maybe show excerpts of the relevant parts of the packaging of `library_a` and `library_b` if possible.

Comment: My understanding was the same as yours. I expected python to go through and install library_a and therefore install the version of library_a required in library_b. However, this is not the case.

Comment: OK. Then there seems to be either a packaging issue (the pinning is not done correctly), or maybe a dependency conflict (two different projects require incompatible versions of the same dependency). But without any more details about A and B, it is hard to tell. Maybe run `pip check`, or `pipdeptree` or something similar, to get some diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can just omit one of the libraries, but not sure without concrete examples.

Anyhow, you can use [requirement specifiers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) for versions that will define rules for versions and pin this rule for libraries you need. Example:

```
install_requires = [
   "python-consul",
   "library_a >=1.2, <2.0",
   "library_b >=1.2, <2.0",
]
```

It can be exact version, greater/less than some version (by major, minor or even build version). Full list of version specifiers (rules) and examples [can be found here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers).